# R: How do I position multi-line tick labels at plots in base R?

Tags: r, plot

In base R plots, I would like to attach multi-line labels to the ticks. Here is a test case, first with simple single-lined labels:

```
# plot some graph
x = (-10:10)/5
y = x^2
plot (y~x,type="l",axes=F)

ticks = c(-2,-1,0,1,2)            # tick positions
labels = c("-2","-1","0","1","2") # tick labels
axis (1,at=ticks,labels=labels)
```

Now I would like to have some labels extend over several lines of text. When I use

```
labels = c("-2","-1","centre\n0","1","2") # some tick labels multi-line
```

the second line of the label is added above the existing labels, leaving insufficient space between the axis and the labels. The tick labels are aligned at the bottom.

How (1) do I have them aligned at the top or; (2) can I move all tick labels down in order to get more space between the axis and the labels?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always find it easier to plot the second line as a new plot on top of the previous one. There is a problem with your data as I see it. I don't really know which is your intention but I will explain the method in detail below.

My problem is that your second labels are the same as the first apart from the word 'centre' which you add in at x=0. Therefore, in my case I have created a new label variable which will only have the second line elements i.e. only the word 'centre' with everything else being blank.

**Data**

This is your data

```
# plot some graph
x = (-10:10)/5
y = x^2
plot (y~x,type="l",axes=F)

ticks = c(-2,-1,0,1,2)            # tick positions
labels = c("-2","-1","0","1","2") # tick labels
axis (1,at=ticks,labels=labels)
```

**Solution1**

Aligned at the bottom properly:

In this case I create a new plot that will have a longer bottom margin. Then I create only a bottom axis for that and set it to colour white so that only the labels are visible:

```
#bottom
#new plot
par(new=TRUE)       
#new margins. default is c(5,4,4,2).First value is the bottom margin.
par(mar=c(4,4,4,2))  
#new labels
labels = c("","","centre","","") # some tick labels multi-line
#make the axis
axis (1,at=ticks,labels=labels, col='white')
```

[image]

If you need centre and zero to be plotted the other way round just change the labels.

**Solution2**

Aligned at the top properly (if I get what you mean):

In your data axis needs to be: `axis(3,at=ticks,labels=labels)`. The three there shows it should be aligned on top

The logic is the same as previously but you need to change the corresponding margin i.e. the third value:

```
#top
par(new=TRUE)
par(mar=c(5,4,3,2))
labels = c("","","centre","","") # some tick labels multi-line
axis (3,at=ticks,labels=labels, col='white')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, your solution no. 1 does the job. Since we are drawing a white axis with ticks onto an existing diagram, I also remove the ticks and use `axis (1,at=ticks,labels=labels, col='white',tck=0)` in order to make sure the white ticks do not cover any part of of the existing labels.

Comment: Great !!. Really glad it was of help :)